# How to use the PropertySource file for unit tests?

Tags: spring, junit

I use Spring in my application, and I want to create a unit test with JUnit. How to run a test with the “production” properties file? How to run a test with a test property file?

This is a data class describing a property file:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "time")
@PropertySource(
        value = ["classpath:config/targets/target.time.config.yml"],
        factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory::class,
        encoding = "UTF-8"
)
data class TargetTimeUnitConfig( ... )
```

This is a test in which I want to test my DateTimeParser with production or specific properties from TargetTimeUnitConfig:

```
@SpringBootTest(classess = [TargetTimeUnitConfig::class, DateTimeParser::class]
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class DateTimeParserTest {
```

I want `DateTimeParserTest` to run only with `TargetTimeUnitConfig`, `DateTimeParser` in the Spring Context.

Now, of course, the file from the specified directory (`classpath:config/targets/target.time.config.yml`) is not loaded.

How to fix it? How to load properties from test resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my solution: 
 
`TargetTimeUnitConfig`

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "time")
@PropertySource(
        value = ["\${spring.config.location:classpath:}\${targetTimeConfig:config/targets/target.time.config.yml}"],
        factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory::class,
        encoding = "UTF-8"
)
data class TargetTimeUnitConfig(
```

`TargetTimeUnitConfigTest`

```
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = [DateTimeParser::class],
        properties = ["targetTimeConfig=targettimeunitconfig/target.time.config.yml"])
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(TargetTimeUnitConfig::class)
class TargetTimeUnitConfigTest {
```

I use 2 environment variables (spring.config.location, targetTimeConfig), which allow running tests and applications with different configs. It also allows you to change the location of production configs.
 
 
But it looks scary, and contains many places for potential errors.